# How to use google adwords api in sandbox?

Tags: google-ads-api

Recently I'm working with google adwords api to get a report using php. Since not familiar with this,  I've no idea about how to generate test accounts. Anyone helps?

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work for about a day now. <3 Google.

Comment: Since Dec 2012 Google has deprecated the use of Adwords API sandbox. They introduced a Test Account on the production environment: [Adwords API blog](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2012/11/21/google-introduces-adwords-api-test-accounts-adwords-api-sandbox-to-sunset-december-15/) and [Using AdWords Test Accounts](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/test-accounts). In these pages you can find explanations on how to set it up

Answer (score 4):

You can build and test your application using the AdWords API Sandbox. The Sandbox allows you to build against a test account without modifying your data or incurring API charges.
http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/sandbox.html

Answer (score 1):

Create test account for Google AdWords using below link

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/accounts-overview?csw=1#test_accounts

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)